# LLVM error (possibly involving msvcrt.dll) when using Julia's PackageCompiler on Azure Devops hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, julia

I am currently in the process of setting up a proper build pipeline for a julia project we are working on that will use [PackageCompiler to create a platform-specific binary](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/apps.html).

This works locally, and it also works on our private build agent (which is running Windows Server 2016 Standard). However when targeting the hosted agents, I *eventually* (40 mins or so of compilation time) get a message like the below.

First thoughts are that this is likely related to a something that's trying to compile against the wrong version of msvcrt.dll, but I'm completely stumped as to how to prepare the build agents in order to obviate this.

Anyone have any ideas? Annoyingly I'm unable to share the repo, but could probably share my packages.toml and manifest.toml files if they would be of use, since there's a fair chance this is triggered by a dependency.

```
2022-11-11T12:45:52.6005686Z - PackageCompiler: compiling nonincremental system image
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2655859Z LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0x995360a8: i32 = X86ISD::BZHI Constant:i32<-1>, 0xa54a4c78, C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:338 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:338 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:357 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2660350Z   0xa52578c8: i32 = Constant<-1>
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2662173Z   0xa54a4c78: i32 = X86ISD::CMOV 0x8928ac18, Constant:i32<8>, TargetConstant:i8<4>, 0x9bf77838, C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:356 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2665934Z     0x8928ac18: i32 = and 0xa54cd800, Constant:i32<7>, int.jl:340 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:325 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:325 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2669490Z       0xa54cd800: i32 = truncate 0x89289140, int.jl:511 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2672691Z         0x89289140: i64 = AssertZext 0xa5665d88, ValueType:ch:i63, int.jl:511 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2676025Z           0xa5665d88: i64,ch = CopyFromReg 0x759b67e8, Register:i64 %0, int.jl:511 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2677961Z             0x9951ed30: i64 = Register %0
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2678235Z       0xa549ffd0: i32 = Constant<7>
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2678515Z     0xa4d46b08: i32 = Constant<8>
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2678789Z     0xa5058970: i8 = TargetConstant<4>
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2680622Z     0x9bf77838: i32 = X86ISD::CMP 0x8928ac18, Constant:i32<0>, promotion.jl:477 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:356 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2684407Z       0x8928ac18: i32 = and 0xa54cd800, Constant:i32<7>, int.jl:340 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:325 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:325 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2687963Z         0xa54cd800: i32 = truncate 0x89289140, int.jl:511 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2691222Z           0x89289140: i64 = AssertZext 0xa5665d88, ValueType:ch:i63, int.jl:511 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2694524Z             0xa5665d88: i64,ch = CopyFromReg 0x759b67e8, Register:i64 %0, int.jl:511 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:355 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:350 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:436 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\VectorizationBase\gTlqN\src\llvm_intrin\masks.jl:467 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\reconstruct_loopset.jl:955 @[ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\LoopVectorization\lCUVJ\src\simdfunctionals\mapreduce.jl:149 ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2696282Z               0x9951ed30: i64 = Register %0
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2696570Z         0xa549ffd0: i32 = Constant<7>
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2696833Z       0xa4f06288: i32 = Constant<0>
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2697114Z In function: julia__vreduce_56412
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2697239Z 
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2697457Z signal (22): SIGABRT
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2697723Z in expression starting at none:0
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2698133Z crt_sig_handler at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\signals-win.c:93
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2698529Z raise at C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2698881Z abort at C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2793396Z .text$_ZN4llvm18report_fatal_errorERKNS_5TwineEb at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2865894Z .text$_ZN4llvm18report_fatal_errorERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.2937602Z .text$_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel14RunSDNodeXFormENS_7SDValueEj at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3009139Z .text$_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel16SelectCodeCommonEPNS_6SDNodeEPKhj at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3078531Z .text$_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_115X86DAGToDAGISel6SelectEPN4llvm6SDNodeE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3151354Z .text$_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel22DoInstructionSelectionEv at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3221260Z .text$_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel17CodeGenAndEmitDAGEv at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3292797Z .text$_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel20SelectAllBasicBlocksERKNS_8FunctionE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3364408Z .text$_ZN4llvm16SelectionDAGISel20runOnMachineFunctionERNS_15MachineFunctionE.part.944 at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3433681Z .text$_ZN12_GLOBAL__N_115X86DAGToDAGISel20runOnMachineFunctionERN4llvm15MachineFunctionE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3505298Z .text$_ZN4llvm19MachineFunctionPass13runOnFunctionERNS_8FunctionE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3576181Z .text$_ZN4llvm13FPPassManager13runOnFunctionERNS_8FunctionE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3646587Z .text$_ZN4llvm13FPPassManager11runOnModuleERNS_6ModuleE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.3719058Z .text$_ZN4llvm6legacy15PassManagerImpl3runERNS_6ModuleE at c:\julia\bin\libLLVM-13jl.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4020841Z operator() at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\aotcompile.cpp:580 [inlined]
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4021763Z jl_dump_native_impl at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\aotcompile.cpp:592
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4030444Z jl_write_compiler_output at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\precompile.c:94
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4041790Z ijl_atexit_hook at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\init.c:207
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4053434Z jl_repl_entrypoint at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jlapi.c:720
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4057263Z mainCRTStartup at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/cli\loader_exe.c:59
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4058300Z BaseThreadInitThunk at C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4059148Z RtlUserThreadStart at C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (unknown line)
2022-11-11T12:51:58.4059989Z Allocations: 111329600 (Pool: 111280265; Big: 49335); GC: 118
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7445980Z ERROR: LoadError: failed process: Process(`'c:\julia\bin\julia.exe' --color=auto --startup-file=no '--cpu-target=generic;sandybridge,-xsaveopt,clone_all;haswell,-rdrnd,base(1)' -O3 '--sysimage=C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_1hF36p\sys.ji' '--project=D:\a\1\s' '--output-o=C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_gDg1itITi3.o' 'C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_ELSHGjSLox'`, ProcessExited(3)) [3]
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7455452Z 
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7456142Z Stacktrace:
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7458165Z   [1] pipeline_error
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7459704Z     @ .\process.jl:565 [inlined]
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7893463Z   [2] run(::Cmd; wait::Bool)
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7895180Z     @ Base .\process.jl:480
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7896888Z   [3] run
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7897975Z     @ .\process.jl:477 [inlined]
2022-11-11T12:52:00.7899706Z   [4] #15
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8197647Z     @ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\ext\TerminalSpinners.jl:157 [inlined]
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8203824Z   [5] spin(f::PackageCompiler.var"#15#16"{Cmd}, s::PackageCompiler.TerminalSpinners.Spinner{Base.PipeEndpoint})
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8204929Z     @ PackageCompiler.TerminalSpinners C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\ext\TerminalSpinners.jl:164
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8206177Z   [6] macro expansion
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8207745Z     @ C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\ext\TerminalSpinners.jl:157 [inlined]
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8260620Z   [7] create_sysimg_object_file(object_file::String, packages::Vector{String}, packages_sysimg::Set{Base.PkgId}; project::String, base_sysimage::String, precompile_execution_file::Vector{String}, precompile_statements_file::Vector{String}, cpu_target::String, script::Nothing, sysimage_build_args::Cmd, extra_precompiles::String, incremental::Bool)
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8261896Z     @ PackageCompiler C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\src\PackageCompiler.jl:364
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8303901Z   [8] create_sysimage(packages::Vector{String}; sysimage_path::String, project::String, precompile_execution_file::Vector{String}, precompile_statements_file::Vector{String}, incremental::Bool, filter_stdlibs::Bool, cpu_target::String, script::Nothing, sysimage_build_args::Cmd, include_transitive_dependencies::Bool, base_sysimage::Nothing, julia_init_c_file::Nothing, version::Nothing, soname::Nothing, compat_level::String, extra_precompiles::String)
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8305352Z     @ PackageCompiler C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\src\PackageCompiler.jl:515
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8332872Z   [9] create_app(package_dir::String, app_dir::String; executables::Nothing, precompile_execution_file::Vector{String}, precompile_statements_file::Vector{String}, incremental::Bool, filter_stdlibs::Bool, force::Bool, c_driver_program::String, cpu_target::String, include_lazy_artifacts::Bool, sysimage_build_args::Cmd, include_transitive_dependencies::Bool)
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8334015Z     @ PackageCompiler C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\src\PackageCompiler.jl:728
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8337368Z  [10] create_app(package_dir::String, app_dir::String)
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8338881Z     @ PackageCompiler C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.julia\packages\PackageCompiler\DKijm\src\PackageCompiler.jl:685
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8340088Z  [11] top-level scope
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8341577Z     @ D:\a\1\s\devops\BuildPackage.jl:5
2022-11-11T12:52:00.8342201Z in expression starting at D:\a\1\s\devops\BuildPackage.jl:5
2022-11-11T12:52:01.5212984Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2022-11-11T12:52:01.5774983Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script: Setup environments and build output
```

Comment: There's no such thing as Windows Server 2017. It probably isn't relevant to your problem, though.

Comment: Ah. Updated with what it actually is - though as you say, probably less relevant than the fact that one of our machines using an older OS seems to work better than the current images available from MS

Comment: What version of hosted agents  did you use?